# ASP.NET calendar drawing control

Tags: asp.net, controls, calendar

I want to make a simple ASP.NET page that draws a months from a calendar and highlights given dates. (I'm *not* looking for a date picker.) What I have is a list of `DateTime` values and I need to display them a a nice way.

Given that I'm a total beginner with ASP, simpler *really* is better. (I'd rather not, I'm willing to hack together something with `StringBuilder` and `<table>` if it's easier).

p.s. I have no budget, so non-free controls will only be of use to other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the standard Calendar Control and use the DayRender event to format the individual days.  I did something similar to this as my first ASP.Net application (a basic event scheduler) where the special dates were stored in a DB.

```
<asp:Calendar id = "objCalendar" runat = "server"
            onDayRender = "objCalendar_DayRender"
            Borderstyle = solid
            >

<%
    public void objCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
    {

        CalendarDay d = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Day;

        string strCurrrentDayDisplay = GetDaySchedule(d.Date.ToShortDateString());

        TableCell c = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Cell;
        if (d.IsOtherMonth) 
        {
            c.Controls.Clear();
        }
        else 
        {
            try 
            {

                c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>" + strCurrrentDayDisplay));
            }
            catch (Exception err) 
            {
                Response.Write (err.ToString());
            }
        }
        d.IsSelectable = false;
    }
%>
```

Comment: It seems to be working. I'm having to beat it into submission (and learning more about ASP.NET in the process) but I don't see any roadblock coming up.

Answer (score 0):

A client side option would be the jQuery [calendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than I'm looking for. It might work but 99% of it is unneeded for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late for this project, but it sounds like [BaseCalendar](http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/) would work.